# How can I compute error degrees of freedom in GAM?

Tags: r

Can anyone help me how to compute error degrees of freedom in GAM? I have never heard before about this parameter in additive models, but one of our reviewer asked us to give it to our GAM table. The table contains the common parameters, i.e. df, F, and p-value for parametric terms and edf, ref.df, F, and P-value for smooth terms.

Thank you so much!

Istvan

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346379/calculating-total-estimated-degrees-of-freedom-for-a-gam

Comment: I suspect the reviewer wants the residual degrees of freedom, see the link above.

Comment: Thank you, Roland!